# How to remove Landesk Core's proxy setting completely in OS X?

Tags: macos, network, proxy

today my Little Snitch detect my proxyhost has requested outgoing connection to Landesk Core even though it has been removed. How can I reset the proxy settings? (FYI, they are not in system settings.)

Answer (score 2):

This is not a network setting, there are still likely components left behind. Probably the best place to ask this question would be landesk.com. For example

http://community.landesk.com/support/thread/16347